# How to implement a #include function into own programming language

Tags: c++, file, import, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I am building my own programming language and I came across a problem. All programming languages, I discovered, have `# include, import, # import` function .I am trying to implement this same function in my own programming language, but I am not sure how to.

Could you explain how import functions operate, how compilers interpret them, and how I can do the same thing in my own programming language?

The project [Project Link](https://github.com/Ashwin-Paudel/Kram)

Comment: Its part of parsing by compiler, as you might be treating const expr or other macro

Comment: There's a big difference between C's `#include` and non-preprocessor-based constructs such as Python's `import` (and even bigger differences between those and, say, Java's `import`) and they're implemented very differently. So you should first decide which construct you want for your language and then think about how to implement it. Preprocessors are generally frowned upon for modern languages, so I wouldn't recommend going in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include` is rather simple actually, if you want to implement it yourself.

The way I usually implement it (when not using a "proper" preprocessor) is to treat the source files as a *stack*.

When you encounter a `#include` directive, get the whole line, parse it and figure out what source file to "include". Then push it onto the stack.

The lexer will use the file at the top of the stack to read from. When it reached end of file the lexer pops the stack and continues reading from the new top.

When the stack is empty, you have finished with the original file.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I will try and do this.

Answer (score -2):

In the C language that is done by the preprocessor. Take a look at [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).